# How can I use an external library in my jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, d3.js, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for my react website using jest running on node. My website uses the D3 diagramming library on some pages, so i load it dynamically using this function:

```js
const loadD3 = function(callback) {
  if (window.d3) {
    if (callback) callback(window.d3);
  } else {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = () => {
      if (callback) callback(window.d3);
    };
    script.onerror = () => {
      if (callback) callback();
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js';
  }
};

export default loadD3;
```

This works just great in my application, but my unit tests all fail because jest does not load the script.

I can obviously mock the whole D3 drawing library, but that's a huge task and seems completely unnecessary. I also want to test that the drawing svg is built correctly, which needs the D3 library to actually run.

I feel like there should be a way to get node to download and execute the D3 script before running the unit test, but I have been searching and reading for a couple of hours now and have come across nothing at all that helps.

So, my question is: can write a version of `loadD3` that will immediately load and execute the D3 library, so that I can write unit tests that check that the correct drawing elements were added to the page?

Comment: I'd install d3 as a [dev dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file) and just import it in your Jest file like any other plugin. It will not be included in your normal bundle, but will be added to the testing bundle by Jest.

Comment: *I can obviously mock the whole D3 drawing library, but that's a huge task and seems completely unnecessary* - well, it's necessary, and you should. Jest fake DOM doesn't cover complex cases and fails to meet the expectation of DOM-oriented lib such as D3. Not to mention that any third-party lib has to be mocked in unit tests if it introduces too much moving parts that lead to flaky tests.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I will try the dev dependency route.

Comment: It would be even better, if you introduce d3.js as a normal dependency also in your production code, not just your unit tests. So install it as a normal dependency and get rid of the script tag with the hard coded d3.js url.